# mysql queries in two tier

Tags: mysql

How to perform the basic MySQL queries using client and data server(Two tier)??
I have tried editing the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file by changing the bind address to 0.0.0.0 then started the mysql and granted privileges. and on client side 'mysql -h IPaddr -u root -p' .But still the server-client connection is not happening.

Comment: do you have a firewall on the server side? check if `3306` port is open (if you used the default one)

Answer (score 0):

If your server is on same machine do not change the bind address keep it as
 
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
 and then try mysql -h localhost -u root -p